# How to show multiple different atibutes (zonal statistics NDVI and H3 Density grid) in ONE hexagon?

Tags: qgis, style, zonal-statistics, hexagonal-grid

I made H3 Density grid with point vector layer and did zonal statistic for NDVI. Now i would like to make a layer which would show both in one hexagone. So for example one hexagone coloured specific green representing NDVI and specific red (depends on density) representing H3 density grid. I am working in Qgis 3.30.

Comment: Red/green contrast is bad practice in caretography, see e.g.: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-living-atlas/mapping/red-green-what/ and https://gistbok.ucgis.org/bok-topics/color-theory You might use a whit to red color ramp for one value and saturation for the other value. I'm still not sure 100% about your intention: can you show a screenshot about how it should look like?

Comment: I guess you're looking for a [bivariate legend](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/BivariateLegend/)